# What ORACLE Update SQL Query for this?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-scripts

I want to update the value of `RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP` to `T2_VAL`.

Thinking of `merge into` but I'm not used to `ORACLE DB`.

```
SELECT t1.INSTANCE_ID
      ,t1.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP
      ,t1.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS t1_val
      ,t2.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS t2_val
      ,t2.PREV_CERTIFICATE_PERMIT_NUMBER
      ,t1.APPROVAL_REFERENCE
FROM LCS_GEN_COPY AS t1
INNER JOIN LCS_GEN_COPY AS t2 ON t2.PREV_CERTIFICATE_PERMIT_NUMBER = t1.APPROVAL_REFERENCE
                              AND t1.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP  = t1.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER
```

[Data from that query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD7dQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE LCS_GEN_COPY t1
SET RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER
                           FROM LCS_GEN_COPY t2
                           WHERE t2.PREV_CERTIFICATE_PERMIT_NUMBER =
                                     t1.APPROVAL_REFERENCE AND t1.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP =
                                     t1.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER);
```

Comment: [21000][1427] ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.
My select statements above gets all the values i need to update

Comment: Then your requirement as is does not make sense.  Try `SELECT DISTINCT` in the subquery.  If that would not work, then you'll need to give us logic for choosing from many possible update values.

Comment: because my query above is all the data i must swap values. It is possible to update the data from that select query?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  The issue is that your query sometimes has more than one `USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER` from which to update a single `RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT t1.INSTANCE_ID
      ,t1.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP
      ,t1.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS t1_val
      ,t2.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS t2_val
      ,t2.PREV_CERTIFICATE_PERMIT_NUMBER
      ,t1.APPROVAL_REFERENCE
FROM LCS_GEN_COPY AS t1
INNER JOIN LCS_GEN_COPY AS t2 ON t2.PREV_CERTIFICATE_PERMIT_NUMBER = t1.APPROVAL_REFERENCE
AND t1.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP  = t1.USER_REFERENCE_NUMBER
) t
SET t.RENEWED_PERMIT_TEMP = t.t2_val
```